# ruby - Once a day passenger is down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

Once a day everyday I receive message in Apache `error_log`:

```
[ pid=3846 thr=139803418023808 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:884 time=2015-03-08 09:04:28.2 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/srv/www/vhosts/****.com/httpdocs': The spawn server died unexpectedly, and restarting it failed.
Backtrace:
 in 'virtual Passenger::SessionPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Client.h:742)
 in 'Passenger::SessionPtr Hooks::getSession(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Hooks.cpp:312)
 in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:585)
```

and the web site is down (500). Passenger version is 3.0.19
Ruby version is 1.8.7-p371. What can I try to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much to go on.  However some years ago I had a rails app using  Ruby 1.8.7 and Passenger 3 that ran fine everywhere but on the production Linux server.  I switched to Phusion's [Ruby Enterprise Edition](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com) on the server and it has been rock-solid since.

Comment: but why it fails everyday in same time? And when I restart Apache - everything is ok

Comment: If a request is causing the failure, the apache access log may have the info you need.  Alternatively, something running on the machine at that specific time is causing a problem.  Check your cron jobs, system logs, etc.